# How do I set cron to run on background?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, init, chkconfig

I am on ubuntu 12.04 and following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps) tutorial. I want to setup cron to run in the background but I don't have a chckconfig in sbin so I can't run `sudo /sbin/chkconfig crond on`

I am fairly new to sys admin stuff so need advice on how to workaround this. I tried searching for the crond command but could not find it. I found another instance of chckconfig but am not sure if this is the same thing I am supposed to use to schedule cron.

```
$ sudo !!
sudo find / -executable -name crond
$ sudo find / -name chkconfig
/etc/bash_completion.d/chkconfig
```

Why is my chckconfig in /etc/bash... Is it the same one used in this tutorial?

How can I set cron to run on background?

```
$ sudo !!
sudo find / -executable -name crond
$ sudo find / -name chkconfig
/etc/bash_completion.d/chkconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

`chkconfig` is a Red Hat feature/command so that doesn't surprise me  that it doesn't work for you on Ubuntu. You can start cron using the `services` command instead.

```
$ sudo services crond start
```

#### Example

```
$ sudo service cron start
cron start/running, process 20209
```

This will run it for the duration that the box is up. To make this service start as part of a bootup you can use this command to configure it,`sudo sysv-rc-conf`, but first you'll likely need to install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

You can then use the UI to select the `crond` service so that it runs at bootup.

[image: ss #1]

You can also use `initctl` and configure the service so that it starts via the command line, but that's a bit more involved than the above. See this article titled: [Manage System Startup and Boot Processes on Linux with Upstart](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/404619-manage-system-startup-and-boot-processes-on-linux-with-upstart) for some details on it.

#### References

- [How to “close” open ports?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74722/how-to-close-open-ports/80333#80333)
- [Manage System Startup and Boot Processes on Linux with Upstart](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/404619-manage-system-startup-and-boot-processes-on-linux-with-upstart)